# Opening a file and matching Engr Label

Tags: python

1.Getting buildid from a buildlocation which is the last word after "\" which is "A1234ABCDE120083.1" in this case

2.After getting the buildid,am opening  a file and then trying to match the line "Engr Label: Data_CRM_PL_177999" to get the label name which is "Data_CRM_PL_177999"

3.Final output should be "Data_CRM_PL_177999"

For some reason I am getting the following syntax error..

```
 import re

 Buildlocation= '\\umor\locations455\INT\A1234ABCDE120083.1'

 Labelgetbuildlabel(Buildlocation)

def getbuildlabel(BuildLocation):
buildid=BuildLocation.split('\')[-1]
Notes=os.path.join(BuildLocation,Buildid + '_notes.txt')
if os.path.exists(Notes):
    try:
        open(Notes)
    except IOError as er:
        pass
    else:
        for i in Notes.splitlines:
        if i.find(Engr Label)
            label=i.split(:)[-1]

print label//output should be Data_CRM_PL_177999
```

Output should be:-

```
Line looks like below in the file
Engr Label: Data_CRM_PL_177999
```

SYNTAX ERROR

```
 buildid=BuildLocation.split('\')[-1]
                                   ^
 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
buildid=BuildLocation.split('\')[-1]
```

The backslash is actually escaping the following quotation mark
So, Python thinks this is actually your string:

```
'[-1])
```

Instead, you should do the following:

```
buildid=BuildLocation.split('\\')[-1]
```

And Python will interpret your string to be

```
\\
```

Interestingly, StackOverflow's syntax highlighter hints at this issue. If you look at your code, it treats everything after that first slash as part of the string, all the way to the end of your code sample.

You also have a few other issues in your code, so I tried cleaning it up a bit for you. (However, I don't have a copy of the file, so obviously, I wasn't able to test this)

```
import re
import os.path

build_location= r'\\umor\locations455\INT\A1234ABCDE120083.1'


label = get_build_label(build_location)

# Python prefers function and variable names to be all lowercase with
# underscore separating words.
def get_build_label(build_location):
    build_id = build_location.split('\\')[-1]
    notes_path = os.path.join(build_location, build_id + '_notes.txt')
    # notes_path is the filename (a string)
    try:
        with open(notes_path) as notes:
            # The 'with' keyword will automatically open and close
            # the file for you
            for line in notes:
                if line.find('Engr Label'):
                    label = line.split(':')[-1]
                    return label
    except IOError:
        # No need to do 'os.path.exists' since notes_path doesn't
        # exist, then the IOError exception will be raised.
        pass
print label
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure file objects don't have a `splitlines()` method -- I think you can either use `xreadlines()` or just the plain file object.

Comment: Ah, ok. The OP originally used `splitlines`, and I don't think I caught that. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Michael -  if condition doesnot seem to working as expected..I dont think its searching line by line..,first line in the notes.txt file has "Request Date: 11/12/2012 5:22:51 PM",I see 51PM as the output
        for line in notes:
                if line.find('Engr Label'):

Comment: @user1795998 -- Hmm, try changing the `if` statement to: `if line.startswith('Engr Label')` and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is escaping the `'` character (see the [escape codes documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals))

Try this line instead:

```
 buildid=BuildLocation.split('\\')[-1]
```

Now you have a backslash escaping the backslash, so your string is a literal backslash.  The other thing you could do would be to tell Python that this string doesn't have any escape codes by prefixing it with an `r` like this:

```
 buildid=BuildLocation.split(r'\')[-1]
```

You've got a number of other problems as well.

The comment character in Python is `#`, not `//`.

I think you're also confusing a filename with a file object.

`Notes` is the name of the file you're trying to open.  Then, when you call `open(Notes)`, you will get back a file object that you can read data from.

So you should probably replace:

```
open(Notes)
```

with

```
f = open(Notes)
```

And then replace:

```
for i in Notes.splitlines:
```

with

```
for line in f:
```

When you do a for loop over a file object, Python will automatically give you a line at a time.

Now you can check each line like this:

```
if line.find("Engr Label") != -1:
  label = line.split(':')[-1]
```